# Read Imagem From Binary File

Tags: c#, .net, binary

I have a file that has a string of binary. But the binary starts from the character 31, ie the image starts to be written from the character 31.
I need this binary from 31 character and then save as an image.

Anyone have an idea that might help me?

Thanks to all

Comment: By "character" 31 do you mean *byte* 31?

Comment: Related earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603909/how-do-i-read-a-binary-file-in-c

Comment: And why doesn't Isak Savo's answer to that question answer this question too?

Comment: so, before charcter 31 I have a string with any text.
And from the position 31 stars my image.

Comment: @tomcamare characters and bytes are not necessarily identical. So which do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer, 31, buffer.Length - 31);
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

---

### (UPDATE)

I assumed you have a byte array and not a stream. If you have a stream then just set the position to 31.

```
fileStream.Position = 31;
Image img = Image.FromStream(fileStream);
```

Comment: So Aliostad i need a Stream to pass in FromStream Parameter. I'm not pass MemoryStream param to Image.FromStream...comprises?

Comment: @tom No I don't understand you. `MemoryStream` is derived from `Stream`, so it can be passed to `Image.FromStream`.

Comment: I assumed you have a byte array and not a stream. If you have a stream then just set the position to 31. See my updates.

Comment: Yes....I can see it now...MemoryStream is derived from Stream...happens that my binary file was corrupted and Image.FromStream was return error. But now I get it to work

Comment: Note that you need to keep the stream open for the lifetime of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you somehow should wind up something along the lines of MemoryStream + Image.FromStream

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.80).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream.aspx

I cant say anything else as "string of binary" doesnt say much about what kind of data you have on the string :/

One final tip, use MemoryStream.Seek to get past those 31 bytes before calling Image.FromStream